# Read the height in GoogleFit in Android

Tags: android, google-fit

I tried to read user's height in Google Fit in android with this code :

```
 DataReadRequest readHeightRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .read(DataType.TYPE_HEIGHT)
            .setTimeRange(FIRST_DAY_OF_MONTH_INMS, NOW_INMS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();
```

But I only got a empty dataset with no dataPoint.

According to the [DataType TYPE_HEIGHT documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataType.html#TYPE_HEIGHT):

> the start time should not be set.

So I tried to remove :

```
.setTimeRange(FIRST_DAY_OF_MONTH_INMS, NOW_INMS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

-> CRASH

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid start time: 0
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.jx.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.DataReadRequest$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
```

And I didn't see any documentation of method to set time range without endtime.

Is it possible to have a functional sample of code ?

[EDIT]

**Solution :**
use a massive time range. I used the presentation of GoogleFit on June 25, 2014 for starting time :

```
DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                .read(DataType.TYPE_HEIGHT)
                .setTimeRange(PresentationOfGoogleFit(June,25,2014), now, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .setLimit(1)
                .build();
```

And it....works ! ;)

[/EDIT]

Comment: Add the logcat please

Comment: you should add a solution as an answer, and even accept it so people who visit this question will see it clearly.

Comment: I am attempting to do the same thing with TYPE_WEIGHT and his solution does not work for me.  I have 2 weight entries  I input yesterday, and nothing comes back with the request, even if I use a massive time range.

Comment: @Andrew :
I use this and it's working :

`DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
    .read(DataType.TYPE_WEIGHT)
   .setTimeRange(PresentationOfGoogleFit(June,25,2014), now, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .setLimit(1)
    .enableServerQueries()
    .build();`

(hope it helps)

Comment: @Piotr It doesn't work for me.  In `ResultCallback`'s `onResult`, the size of `readDataResult.getBuckets().size()` is 0.