# How to get Last Recent Height and Weight from Google Fit Api

Tags: android, google-fit

I want to show users recent Google Fit values like Height , weight , steps etc.

I can easily retrieve values from some defined time range like Yesterday(date) to Today(date) . By setting date in StartTime and EndTime .

And I got related question here on StackOverflow [Read the height in GoogleFit in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482176/read-the-height-in-googlefit-in-android)

They are using something like "PresentationOfGoogleFit(June,25,2014)" , In place of Start Time . But I am not able to use that .

Answer (score 5):

You can get the last weight set using

```
DataReadRequest dataReadRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .read(DataType.TYPE_WEIGHT)
            .setTimeRange(1, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .setLimit(1)
            .build();
```

You can get the height similarly.

You can see similar question at
[Read weight from google fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859491/read-weight-from-google-fit/43870262#43870262)

Comment: Thanks Surya , I got recent Height Weight . One more question that , In Steps etc data that I get from google fit api is different than what i see on google fit app ?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34789614/why-google-fit-steps-counts-differs

Comment: Thanks for link  , I checked there , They have given code like  || DataSource ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
            .setStreamName("estimated_steps")
            .setAppPackageName("com.google.android.gms")
            .build();  ||   But Even after using it , I am getting different data than google fit app .